# Create aliases through shell script

Tags: shell, unix, alias, git-bash

We are using git for source control, which is installed on my windows machine.

In a nutshell I would like to create an alias for a shell script. I figure this out: `alias ulf='. ulf.sh'`. So far so good.

What I want is to add this to a script we have that configures all our git aliases (setaliases.sh). So far what I have read is that setting alias only applies to the current shell and when executing a shell script it does it in another shell. So I found out that you can call `source ./setaliases.sh`. This works right until I close down git-bash. Then I have to recreate the alias.

To sum it up: I want to create a global alias from within a .sh script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can input `source .setalias.sh` in your .bash_login file.

or another way to use alias is add some line in your `.bashrc` like this

```
alias ll='ls -lah'
alias gg='git status -s'
# to call more alias in setalias.sh file
source ~/.setalias.sh
```

Comment: It sounds like it is not possible to do what I want.... The idea was to have a script that would set up the environment with a single script for new developers coming to the team.

Comment: You can source your `setalias` file in `/etc/bashrc`.  This should be read by all users' shells when they log in.